# Test if digits are in ascending order - regular expression

Tags: javascript, regex

Let's say a have a 4 digit number, like this one 1243, is there a way, using a regular expression, to find out if the digits inside the number are in a ascending order, for example this a good number "3579" when "1243" is not

Comment: Why must the answer use a regular expression?

Comment: Now we can clearly see the problem with requiring a regex solution and not clearly specifying the question. As of the time I post this you have two good answers, one regex, one not. They give *different* results for both repeated digits and for inputs with non-decimal values. :)

Comment: Also, both answers think an empty string is a string of ascending integers. :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use a regular expression like this:

```
^0*1*2*3*4*5*6*7*8*9*$
```

Example:

```
var re = /^0*1*2*3*4*5*6*7*8*9*$/;
alert(re.test('3579'));
alert(re.test('1243'));
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/xYgpS/

Comment: Input: ''; Output: true. ;)

Comment: @kojiro: Yes, verifying the length of the input is not within the scope of the question. It clearly specifies that the input is four digits.

Comment: So you're saying that the behavior for an invalid input is undefined. OK, but I'm saying it should be noted. :P

Answer (score 3):

A regular expression is the wrong tool for the job. You're much better off doing this with a simple loop:

```
function isAscending(str) {
    str = str.toString();

    for (var i = 0; i < str.length - 1; ++i) {
        if (str[i] >= str[i + 1]) {
            return false;
        }
    }

    return true;
}
```

Comment: The only thing I would suggest is handling the edge case where `str` contains a non-integer.

Comment: Slightly different implementation `function isAscending(s) {
    var len = s.length;
    return [].every.call(s, function (c, i) { return (++i === len) || c < s[i] });
}`

Answer (score 2):

```
var string="1234";
var orderedString=string.split("").sort().join("");
return (string==orderedString);
```

Comment: You could just `split('')`.

Comment: right, obviously I was influenced by the question and had to put a regex somewhere :-) Answer updated.