# Match portion of regex expression

Tags: regex

It seems like this isn't possible with regex, but I thought it would be worth asking.

I'd like to construct a regex expression that will match ascending digits.  So the "pattern" would be something like

```
^(0123456789)$
```

But if like to be able to Match things like

```
1234
0123
56789
```

The string I'm looking for will always begin and end with the sequence of ascending digits, but I don't know where it will start or how many characters it would contain.

I realize something like

```
(0123456789)|(123456789)|(23456789) ...
```

Is a possibility, but I'm trying to figure out if there is a more elegant way to solve this problem.

Comment: More elegant is *not* using a regex in this case ;)

Comment: Depending on the language of regex you're using, such a thing may be possible by using custom evaluations, but it's not going to be possible using plain-old-regex. In any case, I'd suggest what you want could be more efficiently handled by some other method.

Comment: See [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19128631/test-if-digits-are-in-ascending-order-regular-expression).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Test if digits are in ascending order - regular expression](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19128631/test-if-digits-are-in-ascending-order-regular-expression)

Comment: I might be lacking specificity in my post.  Not really a duplicate of that question, I was looking for ascending, sequential digits.  2345 I want, 2468 I don't.  Sounds like it wouldn't be possible in plain regex.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can accept something like `014` you can do something like `^0?1?2?3?4?5?6?7?8?9?$`

Demo: https://regex101.com/r/pvvAvT/1

Comment: this would also match `00001`. Not sure if that's OK. And it won't match `56789` ;)

Comment: @Julian youre right, I replaced the ```*``` with ```?```

Comment: I like it!  The one problem I'm noticing is that this regex will essentially match any series of ascending digits, `123456789` matches as does `13579`, so it's not quite as flexible as I need it to be.  It should work for some cases though.